# How to find relation between send and received message in twillio

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I am using Copilot API of twillio to send sms. so i am able to send sms to end user. Now if user reply to that sms, i am receiving the callback (PHP Script). Using that callback URL, i am able to get the reply message.

Now i want to do is, i am trying to find a relation between sent and received(which end user reply) message. so i can then forward the reply message to their sender.

I will have UI like below, where user enter the message and number where he wants to receive reply.

But the problem is i am not able to find relation between send/receive message.

Any advice will be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Other than storing the information on your server upon sending/receiving  a message, you could make use of the [cookies stored at Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/how-do-twilio-cookies-work).

When Twilio makes a request to your server and it returns a cookie (a `Set-Cookie` HTTP response header), Twilio stores this cookie and associates it with the `From` and `To` numbers for the incoming call or SMS message.

A little caveat to this is the fact that this cookie is only stored for four hours, so unless that works for you, I'd suggest using the `from` & the `to` as composite keys to find a relation.

Hope this helps you